# Visual Studio Test Platform Installer using Service connection

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

- In azure I created a nuget service connection named "my_service_connection_to_nuget".
- In the azure pipeline I use the following task:

```
    - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
      displayName: '= Visual Studio Test Platform Installer'
      inputs:
        packageFeedSelector: customFeed
        customFeed: 'my_service_connection_to_nuget'
```

Sadly it seems not to be possible to use the service connection.
How can I use the concept of service connections with VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller? Or is there another concept I hadn't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `customFeed` is NOT nuget service connection, but `a custom feed` or `a package management feed in Azure DevOps or TFS`.

As per the task [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/visual-studio-test-platform-installer-v1?view=azure-pipelines):

[image]

For example, you can use Azure DevOps nuget feed in the task:

1. Upload `Microsoft.TestPlatform` package to your DevOps nuget feed.(you can search the package in nuget upstream,and `save to feed`, it will save the package to your feed.)
   [image]
2. Add your account to feed as `owner` role.
   [image]
3. Get the feed url:

[image]
4. Create personal access token(PAT) for the account. and use the token in the task:

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Visual Studio Test Platform Installer'
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'customFeed'
    versionSelector: 'latestPreRelease'
    customFeed: 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org}/_packaging/{feedname}/nuget/v3/index.json'
    username: 'wade'
    password: '$(token)'
```

[image]

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft thanks for your help.  I use use azure devops on-premises and want to keep the nuget packages in a nexus repository. To store the the authentication credentials in azure I made a nuget service connection to my nexus repo manager. Now I can't use that. Isn't that a strange concept? If I understand you right I have to put the nuget packages into the azure nuget repo and refer that in the task.

Comment: Yes, you cannot use nuget service connection in the task as it's not the usage. You can store the package in on-prem ADO server feed, and follow task above to install it. Or you need to remove the task but download the package file from nexus repo, and install it via command line in pipeline, but it could be more complicated. It's recommended to put it in the local ADO feed.

Comment: Thank's again @wade-zhou-msft . Is it possible to make a ADO feed that does proxy the nexus repo manager?

Comment: No, it's not supported to proxy the nexus repo by ADO feed. For the task, you need to put the package in your ADO feed.